# SQL insert into table. have value = (value before inserted) + a number(ex 1000)

Tags: mysql, sql

New to SQL. I am doing an insert into, where i want to copy all my existing daya, but in the id field, add 1000 to the id. Ex, if the old id was 1, i want the new id to be 1001.

TABLE EXAMPLE of what i would like the output to be

```
id      fname    lname
1       tina     smith
2       mark     brown
3       lucy     cox
1001    tina     smith
1002    mark     brown
1003    lucy     cox
```

i know the insert statement would be similar to this below. just cant figure out how to set up the id in that select query. Would you put something like (id +1000), or is there some other way to add a value?

```
insert into tablenamehere
(id, fname, lname)
select
(id, fname, lname)
from tablenamehere
```

I would expect the results to be the value 1000 added to my original id numbers. As shown in the table above. So if my ID was 1, there would now be a new ID 1001 with the same first and last name as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Seems like Islingre beat me to it. But as (s)he says, remember to turn off IDENTITY, or it will throw an error.

```
  INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description, Picture)
  SELECT (CategoryID + 1000), CategoryName, Description, Picture FROM Categories
```

Just tested this on a Northwind DB, and it works perfect:

[image]

Comment: awesome thanks! Glad to know i was on the right track!

Comment: @pink If an answer answered your question, please mark it as Accepted Answer

Answer (score 1):

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (id, fname, lname)
    SELECT id + 1000, fname, lname
    FROM mytable;
```

That's it.

Comment: Eventhough you should always check no ```id``` is doubled with this.. If it is a ```PRIMARY KEY``` (as should be), the DB might give you an error otherwise.

Comment: awesome thanks! Glad to know i was on the right track!